# Non-English String in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to create a String like this in Spring Boot:

```
   model.setBody("Bạn đã nhận được một báo cáo mới");
```

but when I use

```
model.getBody().toString()
```

I received a weird String like this:

> B?n ?ã nh?n ???c m?t báo cáo m?i

I tried it out on Java Application and it worked fines. I did some research on Google abou thow to set utf-8 and more but its still no help. Anyone know why it behave so weird like that?
P/s: I'm using

> spring_boot_version=1.5.8.RELEASE

I'm using gradle

Comment: You should set the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Spring's `CharacterEncodingFilter` in your `web.xml`. You need to make sure this filter is the first one in the file.

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
    <init-param>  
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>  
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
    <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to set encoding for application.

One of the ways is set below properties in application.properties in spring-boot application.

```
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8 # the encoding of HTTP requests/responses
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true # enable http encoding support
spring.http.encoding.force=true # force the configured encoding
```

For other ways see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140118/spring-boot-mvc-wrong-encoded-post-request)